# Session key is the same throughout the session, can this behavior be exploited?

Tags: web-application, csrf, session-management

This application uses session key instead of CSRF token but this session key is the same throughout the session, it's not changing. It only changes if I logout and then login again to the application.

1. Is session key and CSRF token similar?
2. Can this behavior of key remaining same throughout the session be exploited by an attacker in any way?

Comment: Session keys and CSRF tokens are two completely different concepts. I assume that the session key is stored as cookie? If so, then CSRF *may* be possible in certain situations.

Comment: Can you please explain what's the difference between them or point me to any reference please?

No, session key is sent as parameters in post request body (like any other normal data we send to the server in post request body) and in some part its one of the endpoint where post request is being made.

Comment: What you think can it still be exploited?

Comment: [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) is usually a good source

Comment: In this particular case I think its acting as a CSRF token, why I believe so? Actually CSRF token is used because session cookies are sent with a request and in this particular case session key is not inside the cookie, in most part of the application its being sent as a parameter in post request body.

Comment: The idea of a CSRF token is that it's per-action. If the session is stored in a cookie, then it is automatically sent via every request. If the session is also used as CSRF token, then the token is also always sent, and thus defeats the purpose of a CSRF token.

Comment: Yes, but this remains same in all the requests throughout the session. Can this behavior be exploited? 

Again for most part of the application the its sent as a parameter in post request's body.

Comment: Yes, storing the session key in the DOM means that it's trivial to read via a possible XSS exploit. It's better to store the session key as a cookie with Secure and HTTPOnly flag.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior. The session identifier stays the same throughout a session, so from logging in to logging out. This does not introduce vulnerabilities.

A CSRF token is normally bound to a session, but does not have any other relation with a session token.

Comment: This session key is not inside the cookie or in other words we can say its not part of the cookie, its being sent as a parameter in post request's body (and this key is same throughout the session as I mentioned) and in some parts of the application its one of the endpoint where post request is being made.